# Correct AspectJ Pointcut Expression

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I have custom JodaJdbcTemplate class. It is simple queryImpl that can execute queries.

for example

```
jodaJdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO bla bla...");
```

I need to catch specific exception (**DeadlockLoserDataAccessException**) every time when this method is executed.

I wrote the Aspect class and have such aspect configuration:

```
@Around("execution( * org.springframework.jdbc.core.JodaJdbcTemplate (..))")
```

Get exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.resolvePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:317)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:295)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:208)
```

Guys, what i did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I've rechecked it and the pointcut `execution(* org.springframework.jdbc.core.JodaJdbcTemplate.*(..))` will run around every method on this class, if that is what you want.
Now if you want to catch an exception then you should consider `@AfterThrowing`.
I've this running with spring-aop-3.2.2.RELEASE, so I can send it, if it still doesn't work for you...

Comment: No, it didn't help. Anyway, thank for your help - i'm very appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the space from "execution( *" -> "execution(*".
Otherwise it look fine to me.

Comment: didn't help, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

   @AfterThrowing(
  pointcut = "execution( * org.springframework.jdbc.core.JodaJdbcTemplate.update(..))",
  throwing= "error")
    public void logAfterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable error) {
    System.out.println("Exception : " + error);
    }
}
```